# How to set height & width of Edittext so that when i type something in edittext beside button should become visible

Tags: android-layout, android

I have `EditText` & `Button` in `LinearLayout`. I have made `Button` invisible now & my `EditText` is `fill parent` .

However when I want to enter something in `EditText`the width of edit text should wrap &  `Button` beside should become visible. Any code snippet would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClickMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code :

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Button btnClickMe=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickMe);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            btnClickMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you think when i will enter something the edittext will wrap & button become visible

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the `EditText` to `fill_parent`. You can try to use :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width = "0dp"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    />

<YourButton/>
```

and i assume your `LinearLayout` is `horizontal` orientated.

Answer (score 0):

Button has setVisibility method. To make visible use the following:

```
Button button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
     <EditText android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         anroid:layout_width="0dp" />
     <Button android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I assume you already have the code for showing the button when you type something in the EditText

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Register [OnFocusChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) to your EditText.
- Override [`onFocusChange()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html#onFocusChange%28android.view.View,%20boolean%29) and do the following if `hasFocus== true`:

  - Change the LayoutParameters of your EditText to be wrap_content in both Width and Height.
  - Set your Button to be Visisble.